# if else inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I got an error:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

My JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attention": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attention": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attention": 0
        }
    ]
}
_handleOutput() {
    var att = data.attention.map(function (data) {
      return data.attention
    });
}
console.log(att)
```

Is it possible to use if-else to compare the JSON output data to React `DOM`? Something like this:

```
if (data.attention === true || "1") {
    return <span>&#9989;</span>;
} else {
    return <span>&#10060;</span>;
}
```

then i output into table list `<td>{this._handleOutput()}</td>`

Comment: Sure you can use control structures in closures. But your problem is probably the condition `data.attention === true || "1"`. It's not doing what you think. You cannot make such a shortcut. You have to write `data.attention === true || data.attention === "1"` or something like that...

Comment: `data.attention` is wrong: 1. There is no `data` variable defined here. 2. You have an object with a *property* data, so you have to do `obj.data`. 3. `attention` is not a property on the array, either.

Comment: @android1751 in react you can define like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58688627/6544460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake in the tried solution

1. data.attention is not an array.
2. Check directly with value 1

**Solution**

- Using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a copy of jsx elements.
- Using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) while looping through the array instead of writing item.attention
- Checking the value so basically we can use ternary check (true ? 1: 0), since the value of attention is either 1 or 0 which represents true or false we can use it in this way.

**Notes to improve**

- Instead of using wrapping with div you can use [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```js
const jsonData = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "attention": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attention": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "attention": 0
    }
  ]
}

const App = () => {
    return ( <div> 
              {
                jsonData.data.map(({attention}) => {
                 return (
                 <div>
                    {
                      attention ? <span>&#9989;</span>
                      :
                      <span>&#10060;</span>
                    }
                   </div>
                 )
                })
              }
            </div>
          )
        }

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let obj = {
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            attention: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            attention: 2
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            attention: 0
        }
    ]
}
```

inside component define render function

```
render(){
return (
    <div>
     {obj.data.map(a=>{
      if(a.attention===1) 
       return <span>&#9989;</span>

       return <span>&#10060;</span>;  
     })}
    </div> 
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is `array`, not `data.attention` for this `map` is not working. `map` is working in the array.

Comment: rather adding it as answer you have enough reputation to comment one line.Try not to increase the answer section until unless its a code snippet or some long description.

Comment: @AyushiKeshri Thanks for your suggestion. I always try to add code snippet but for this can not for some office work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call map on a number field. It should be `data.map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Data is your array not data.attention. So use like this:

```
 {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "attention": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "attention": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "attention": 0
            }
        ]
    }

    var att = data.map(function (data) {
      return data.attention
    });
    console.log(att)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "attention": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "attention": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "attention": 0
    }
]

var att = data.map(data => {
  console.log(data);

  if (data.attention === 1) {
    return '<span>&#9989;</span>';
  } else {
    return 'Not Fount';
  }
});

console.log(att);
```